# Multiple properties as index signature in typescript

Tags: typescript, redux

So, I'm developing a pagination system, and I'm trying to store all the pages the user has searched for so far in our redux store.

I would like to implement a type that looked like this:

```
{skip, limit, filter}: [](this one is an array of numbers)
```

So I could for example, store a new page inside it like this:

```
pages[0,10,array] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
pages[10,20,array] = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

So, in a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is create a map that uses three different types as it's index, and an array of numbers as it's value.

I did some research about this, and was able to find some [documentation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) on mapped types, but that doesn't really solve my problem.

```
type Index = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type FromIndex = { [k in Index]?: number }

const good: FromIndex = {b:1, c:2}

// Error:
// Type '{ b: number; c: number; d: number; }' is not assignable to type 'FromIndex'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'd' does not exist in type 'FromIndex'.
const bad: FromIndex = {b:1, c:2, d:3};
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thank you for your time so far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multiple keys is not possible. You can, however, work around this by simply concatenating the keys to a string and use that string as a unique identifier:

```
const pages:{[key:string]: Array<number>} = {};

// Using just toString() or simple types
const uniqueKey:string = `${skip} ${limit} ${filter}`;
pages[uniqueKey] = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

// Using JSON.stringify()
const uniqueKeyWithObjectInside:string = `${JSON.stringify(obj1)} ${JSON.stringify(obj2)} ${JSON.stringify(obj3)}`;
pages[uniqueKeyWithObjectInside] = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```